# How can I achieve a streak free windshield?

Tags: cleaning, windshield

I can never quite get the streak free shine on my windshield from using Windex.

Is there another product that works better?

Comment: Are you talking about cleaning the inside or the outside of the windshield?  Some of the answers below don't seem practical for the inside (e.g. how do you wash and rinse with soap and water without creating a huge puddle on your dashboard?).

Comment: Both, last attempt streaked pretty good inside...

Comment: See my answer - Invisible Glass wipes work well inside and outside

Answer (score 7):

Clean with soap and water, rinse clear, then dry with a microfiber cloth.  The key is the microfiber cloth.

Answer (score 2):

I clean with standard glass cleaner, then dry with newspaper.

Answer (score 2):

I personally use Stoner Invisible Glass wipes (good for inside and outside). However, as mfr suggested, water + soap, rinse, and then microfiber will work just as well.

Most cleaning solutions will get you 95% of the way there no problem; if you want that extra 5% you need a good microfiber cloth.

Answer (score 1):

I wash as normal with the rest of the vehicle, then rinse with a weak vinegar/water solution (soft water preferably). Then dry with chamois leather.

Answer (score 1):

Wash in the shade. If you do not clean off the soap/cleaner before it dries, streaks will appear. Also use a quality glass cleaner. As mentioned, "Invisible Glass" is a great one that I use and don't have streaks with.

Also be sure there is no wax on the window. Some car wash soaps have integrated waxes in them. They are not really a good replacement for a real wax application and they tend to "wax" the windows as well.